# WSO2 APIM Headers Schema Validation

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

Unable to validate Header Parameters by schema validator. Is there any way to do this? I am Able to validate Json Body Schema but unable to validate headers. I added header with required parameter butWSO2-APIM 3.1 not throwing any exception even the required header is missed. To achieve this need to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json schema validate validates only request/response body.It could be an improvement in future [1]
[1]. https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/9011